# No values given for wildcard, expand issue

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm new to python and snakemake. I'm trying to create a bed file from trf output. I'm reusing code from github, but I don't need to do all of the things the github code does. I've pulled the relevant trf sections from here:
https://github.com/mrvollger/assembly_workflows/blob/master/workflows/mask.smk

When I run the script, I get an error:

```
No values given for wildcard 'ID,\\d+'.
  File "/project/90daydata/cotton_genomics/genomes/GB0085/reference/trf.smk", line 107, in <module>
```

From what I've read on other posts, the issue isn't really about the wildcard constraint, rather the expand function in line 107. I'm still figuring out how expand works, but I'm missing something and don't understand how to fix it. It is mind-bending to me still. Any help is appreciated.

```
import os 
import sys
import re
import re
import pysam 
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from snakemake.remote.HTTP import RemoteProvider as HTTPRemoteProvider
from snakemake.remote.FTP import RemoteProvider as FTPRemoteProvider
FTP = FTPRemoteProvider()
HTTP = HTTPRemoteProvider()

today = date.today()
DATE =  today.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")


SDIR=os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(srcdir("env.cfg"))+"/..")
shell.prefix(f"source {SDIR}/env.cfg ; set -eo pipefail; ")

# delete if not debug
DEBUG=True
def tempd(fname):
    if(DEBUG):
        return(fname)
    return(temp(fname))


FASTA = os.path.abspath( config["fasta"] )
FAI = FASTA + ".fai"
assert os.path.exists(FAI), f"Index must exist. Try: samtools faidx {FASTA}"

# WILDCARDS
NIDS = min(200, len(open(FAI).readlines()) )
IDS = [ "{:03}".format(ID+1) for ID in range(NIDS) ]
# IDS = [ 1 ]

#x = range(6)
#for n in x:
#   print(n)

for y in range(len(IDS)):
    print(IDS[y], "+++")

print(open(FAI).readlines())

SM = "asm"
if("sample" in config): SM = config["sample"]
SPECIES = "human"
if("species" in config): SPECIES = config["species"]
THREADS = 16
if("threads" in config): THREADS = config["threads"]


SMS = [SM]

wildcard_constraints:
    SM="|".join(SMS),
    ID="\d+",

# FASTA_FMT = f"Masked/temp/{SM}_{{ID}}.fasta"
FASTA_FMT = f"temp/{SM}_{{ID}}.fa"
TRFBED = os.path.abspath(f"{SM}_{{ID}}.trf.bed")

rule split_fasta:
    input:
        fasta = FASTA,
    output:
        fastas = tempd(expand(FASTA_FMT, ID=IDS)),
    threads: 1
    resources:
        mem=8
    run:
        fasta = pysam.FastaFile(input["fasta"])
        outs = [open(f,"w+") for f in output.fastas]
        outidx = 0
        for name in fasta.references:
            seq = fasta.fetch(name)
            outs[outidx].write( ">{}\n{}\n".format(name, seq) )
            outidx += 1
            if(outidx == NIDS): outidx = 0 

        for out in outs: 
            out.close()



# This runs trf on the temp output
rule run_trf:
    input:
        fasta = FASTA_FMT,
    output:
        dat = tempd(FASTA_FMT + ".dat")
    benchmark:
        FASTA_FMT + ".bench"
    resources:
        mem=24,
    threads: 1
    shell:"""
trf {input.fasta} 2 7 7 80 10 50 15 -l 25 -h -ngs > {output.dat}
"""

#for yy in range(len(IDS)):
#   print(IDS[yy], "++")

rule trf_bed:
    input:
        dats = expand(rules.run_trf.output.dat, ID=IDS, SM=SM),
    output:
        bed = TRFBED,
    resources:
        mem=8,
    threads: 1
    run:
        trf = []
        header = '#chr start end PeriodSize CopyNumber ConsensusSize PercentMatches PercentIndels Score A C G T Entropy Motif Sequence'.split()
        for datf in input.dats:
            chrom = None
            sys.stderr.write( "\r" + datf )         
            with open(datf, 'r') as dat:
                for line in dat:
                    splitline = line.split()
                    if( line.startswith("Sequence:") ):
                        chrom = int(line.split()[1].strip())
                        #sys.stderr.write(chrom + "\n")
                    elif( line.startswith("@") ):
                        chrom = splitline[0][1:].strip() # grab everything after the @ in the first word
                    else:
                        # Catch index errors when line is blank
                        try:
                            # Check if in header sequence (all non-header lines start with an int: start pos)
                            try:
                                int(splitline[0])
                            except ValueError:
                                continue
                            trf.append([chrom] + splitline[ 0: (len(header)-1) ] )
                        except IndexError:
                            pass
        trf = pd.DataFrame(trf, columns=header)
        print(trf.shape)
        
        trf["start"] = trf["start"].astype(int)
        trf.sort_values(by=["#chr", "start"], inplace=True)
        print("done sorting trf")

        trf.to_csv(output.bed, sep="\t", index=False)

rule trf:
    input:
        bed = rules.trf_bed.output.bed
```

Comment: Please post the full error-output (including stacktrace). Additionally mark the line in your code, where the error originates with a comment. We can't find it with `line 107`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).